# Why is there a delay in my MouseUp event when I right-click, but not left-click?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to detect left-clicks and right-clicks that occur in an image frame, with the status bar and cells displaying different things based on what type of click is detected. I originally did this with a MouseDown event, but that was causing a delay for both left and right clicks. When I switched the MouseUp, the delay for left-clicks was significantly minimized but the delay for right-clicks persisted. By delay, I mean that when I do 5 clicks at a reasonable speed, only the 1st, 3rd, and 5th clicks are recorded. When doing right-clicks slow enough, all 5 can be detected, but for my purposes, I need to detect them when clicked at a normal (160 bpm) speed.

```
Public Sub Image1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, _
  ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, _
  ByVal Y As Single)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Range("X2:Z2").Insert

    Range("X2") = Round(X)
    Range("Y2") = Round(Y)

    If Button = 1 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Hit Recorded"
        Range("Z2") = "H"
        ClearStatusBar
    ElseIf Button = 2 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Miss Recorded"
        Range("Z2") = "M"
        ClearStatusBar
    End If

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling_Math(X, 10) >= 310 Then
        Range("X2") = 310
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: You might want to try hooking the mouse, it may help confirm if the frame is ignoring messages from the OS or if they aren't being sent.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I'm not very experienced with VBA.